# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 

Tags: php

Im using recaptcha but when the user type incorrect captcha i have an errror called: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." whats the problem on it?

Thanks.

Comment: It didn't expect the `.` there.

Comment: More like PEBKAC error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that some code is only loaded and executed when the user entered an incorrect answer, and that there's a syntax error in this code. Read the error message, it should tell you whereabouts the problem is (file and line number).

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error in your JavaScript.  You can run [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) on the JavaScript output by PHP.